# can not install rubygame successfully

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, rubygame

my os is OSX 10.8.2. i have followed the instructions from [rubygame wiki](https://github.com/rubygame/rubygame/wiki/Mac-Install-Guide), and
everything is ok during my installation. However, when I require the rubygame in my ruby script, something happend:

```
    irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygame'
    ArgumentError: callbacks cannot have variadic parameters
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.2.0/lib/ffi/library.rb:365:in `callback'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ruby-sdl-ffi-0.4/lib/ruby-sdl-ffi/sdl/mac.rb:161
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ruby-sdl-ffi-0.4/lib/ruby-sdl-ffi/sdl.rb:80
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ruby-sdl-ffi-0.4/lib/ruby-sdl-ffi/sdl.rb:67:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ruby-sdl-ffi-0.4/lib/ruby-sdl-ffi/sdl.rb:67
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rubygame-2.6.4/lib/rubygame/main.rb:22
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rubygame-2.6.4/lib/rubygame.rb:44
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rubygame-2.6.4/lib/rubygame.rb:29:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rubygame-2.6.4/lib/rubygame.rb:29
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/xrs1133/ruby-sdl-ffi/commit/0b721ac4659b4c08cda5aa2f418561a8a311e85b) fixed it for me. But basically ruby-sdl-ffi and Rubygame look unmaintained. I would recommend against using them unless someone adopts these projects.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it must be the version problem on the link you given they mention only 10.5 and 10.3. You must check the changelog for new changes, it might happend sometimes